# array filter in python?

Tags: python, list, filter

For example, I have two lists

```
 A           = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
subset_of_A  = [6, 9, 12]; # the subset of A


the result should be [7, 8, 10, 11]; the remaining elements
```

Is there a built-in function in python to do this?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

If the order is not important, you should use `set.difference`. However, if you want to retain order, a simple list comprehension is all it takes.

```
result = [a for a in A if a not in subset_of_A]
```

**EDIT:** As delnan says, performance will be substantially improved if `subset_of_A` is an actual `set`, since checking for membership in a `set` is O(1) as compared to O(n) for a list.

```
A = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
subset_of_A = set([6, 9, 12]) # the subset of A

result = [a for a in A if a not in subset_of_A]
```

Comment: And this can be improved vastly by making `subset_of_A` a real `set`, which gives `O(1)` membership test (instead of `O(n)` as with lists).

Answer (score 105):

Yes, the [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) function:

```
filter(lambda x: x not in subset_of_A, A)
```

Comment: Note that in Python 2, `filter` returns the list itself, while in Python 3, it returns an iterator.

Comment: @modulitos `list(filter(...))`

Answer (score 11):

`set(A)-set(subset_of_A)` gives your the intended result set, but it won't retain the original order. The following is order preserving:

```
[a for a in A if not a in subset_of_A]
```

Comment: This is wrong, it should be "if a not in", NOT "if not a in"

Answer (score 9):

No, there is no build in function in python to do this, because simply:

```
set(A)- set(subset_of_A)
```

will provide you the answer.

Comment: While this works for his example, there may be problems if elements are repeated in the list A.

Comment: @AlokMysore Yet, doesn't `set()` remove duplicates by precisely making the array a set?

Answer (score 5):

`tuple(set([6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]).difference([6, 9, 12]))`

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
set(A).difference(subset_of_A)
```

Answer (score 3):

This was just asked a couple of days ago (but I cannot find it):

```
>>> A = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
>>> subset_of_A = set([6, 9, 12])
>>> [i for i in A if i not in subset_of_A]
[7, 8, 10, 11]
```

It might be better to use `set`s from the beginning, depending on the context. Then you can use [set operations](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set) like other answers show.

However, converting lists to sets and back only for these operations is slower than list comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Set` type:

```
A_set = Set([6,7,8,9,10,11,12])
subset_of_A_set = Set([6,9,12])

result = A_set - subset_of_A_set
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = set([6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12])
>>> sub_a = set([6, 9, 12])
>>> a - sub_a
set([8, 10, 11, 7])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> A           = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
>>> subset_of_A  = [6, 9, 12];
>>> set(A) - set(subset_of_A)
set([8, 10, 11, 7])
>>>
```