# Python find duplicates array operations

Tags: python

How can I form an array (c) composed of elements of b which are not in a?

```
a=[1,2,"ID123","ID126","ID124","ID125"]
b=[1,"ID123","ID124","ID125","343434","fffgfgf"]
c= []
```

Can this be done without using a list comprehension?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640630/array-filter-in-python

Comment: can it be done without list comprehension

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697432/python-how-to-find-list-intersection)

Comment: @Rajeev: why do you want to do it without a list comprehension?  We can't guess at your requirements, you need to explain these things.

Comment: I am expecting simple things like a-b and i tried list comptrehensiom

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the lists are long, you want to make a set of `a` first:

```
a_set = set(a)
c = [x for x in b if x not in a_set]
```

If the order of the elements don't matter, then just use sets:

```
c = list(set(b) - set(a))
```

Python lists don't offer a direct `-` operator, as Ruby arrays do.

Answer (score 1):

Using [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is most straight forward:

```
[i for i in b if i not in a]
c
['343434', 'fffgfgf']
```

*However*, if you really did **not** want to use list comprehension you could use a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/):

```
c = (i for i in b if i not in a)
```

This will also not generate the result list all at once in memory (in case that would be a concern).

Answer (score 0):

The following will do it:

```
c = [v for v in b if v not in a]
```

If `a` is long, it might improve performance to turn it into a set:

```
a_set = set(a)
c = [v for v in b if v not in a_set]
```